# Auto increment from specific value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, ado.net

I am updating rows from a Dataset. There are two values that need to be unique in addition to the primary key. I have put unique constraints on them.

In my application both values are assigned when creating a new entry. When the user chooses to save, some rows may fail to update because another user has already claimed those values.

Is there a way to automatically choose the next available number in SQL Server. I know I can do it in the application itself, but I was wondering if there was a server side solution to this.

Is don't think identity columns is a solution, because I need to supply the minimum number when updating.

Comment: Have you looked at sequences?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: Sequences are only available in 2012+. What version is your database?

Comment: Unless you use an identity, or a sequence if you are on 2012 or later, you are going to have concurrency issues. Seems kind of strange that you need to have 3 columns of unique values in a single table.

Comment: I am using 2012, and sequences looks like the perfect solution.